# Using VBA to search on a website

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to wrap my head around this as looking online this code though basic from what i can understand as no knowledge of VBA, Should at least just put in the search bar for google the word I put in. But it doesn't seem to am I missing something or have I done it completely wrong any pointers?

I know it won't hit enter as not been added in yet, It will load the google page but that is it.

Ideally after getting it to search is to expand on it to update an internal website with the information from a spreadsheet

Also if anyone knows any good places to see for VBA code meaning ect, please advise.

```
Sub test()
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "google.com"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "bbc"
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at present you are only after the search results for a search term you could use either of the following where the searchTerm = "BBC" is concatenated into the URL. XMLHTTP60 would be what ever version is for your Excel as the XML reference library.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Getinfo2()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim searchTerm As String

    searchTerm = "BBC"

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&source=hp&ei=Ep2yWvPDN8visAfVwIagBg&q=" & searchTerm & "&oq=" & searchTerm & "&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i131i67k1l3j0i131k1j0i131i67k1l3j0i67k1j0i131i67k1.1897.1897.0.3045.3.2.0.0.0.0.134.134.0j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.269.6...135.zC-Z7B8DrM4", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'add stuff to a collection etc
    Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    '......


End Sub
```

Or with IE

```
Public Sub ScrapeIE()

    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim ihtml As Object
    Dim searchTerm As String

    searchTerm = "BBC"
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE

        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&source=hp&ei=Ep2yWvPDN8visAfVwIagBg&q=" & searchTerm & "&oq=" & searchTerm & "&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i131i67k1l3j0i131k1j0i131i67k1l3j0i67k1j0i131i67k1.1897.1897.0.3045.3.2.0.0.0.0.134.134.0j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.269.6...135.zC-Z7B8DrM4"

        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set ihtml = .document


       ' .Quit

    End With

    Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  Do Google searches and count the number of hits?  Try the script below and give me feedback.

```
Sub Gethits()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getelementbyid("resultStats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Put your search terms in ColumnA and run the script.

[image]